# Javascript: unable to escape backslash in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, escaping, backslash

Very simply, I want to assign a variable the value of a single backslash character. The problem is:

```
var myVar = '\';     // breaks because the backslash escapes the closing quote
var myVar = '\\';    // now myVar has two backslashes
```

Everything I can find says that you escape a backslash with a backslash, which is what I have always known to be generally true.  However, when I run this in IE I get two backslashes instead of one.

Here's a screenshot of the IE debugger attempting to replace a # with a .  This problem occurs anywhere I try to escape a backslash with a string literal - the string.replace() function yields the same error.

[image: screenshot]

**[Edit]**

Thanks for the comments.  In the short term I'll probably use octal or hexadecimal ascii as several people have recommended.  But what I would really like is to understand why I can't just escape the backslash.

Here's a better screenshot without the string.replace function.  Same result.

[image]

**[/Edit]**

Comment: I can't read the screenshot but `var myVar = '\\'` will result in one backslash character in the string. Make a jsfiddle or paste the code and instructions to reproduce

Comment: what version of ie are you using/looking at?

Comment: Guess it just shows escaped characters escaped in the debugger. Did you try to alert it? (with `alert(myVar)`)

Comment: The downvotes are likely because the problem he's so worried about doesn't even exist.  A single `alert(dirPath)` would prove that.

Comment: It's a valid problem because the 'correct' behavior for a debugger is ambiguous. `'\'` and `'\\'` are both logical expressions of a single backslash, in their own way. Given that the inspectors for Chrome, Firefox and Opera all display the value as `'\'`, this doesn't seem like a stupid mistake to make.  I think this is useful information to have available on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out @Prusse had it right: it wasn't a problem escaping the backslash, the problem was that the IE debugger renders `'\'` as `'\\'`.  In my case I had an underlying problem that behaved the same way a mangled string would have so it took a while to track this down.

Solution:

> Did you try to alert it? (with alert(myVar))
>   -Prusse

Comment: That's not exactly a problem when you understand that it's doing it and why.  The string being in quotes (when the actual value doesn't  have them) generally means it's a string literal, and is a clue that it's being displayed as the language would expect you to type it in (eg: `"\"` would not be a valid JS string literal, but `"\\"` is, so that's what the debugger shows).

Comment: Sure, but until you give the issue that much thought, it seems pretty counter intuitive. That's a personal opinion, but it's consistent with the behavior of every (respected) browser. Ultimately this boils down to user expectation though, which puts it firmly beyond the realm of logic ;)

Comment: FF does it.  IE does it.  I'd argue that any JS debugger or web browser that *doesn't* do it is messed up.  (Which sadly includes Chrome, it seems...i may file a bug report.)

Comment: So, FireBug is broken too.  (I was talking about FF's built in "web console", which includes a REPL that does the right thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's bothering you too much, use octal or hexadecimal ascii code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
var backslash = String.fromCharCode(92);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/Sjja3/

**EDIT:**
I don't see any need for the `replace` function. Why don't you just do this? It works fine for me in IE.

```
if( dirPath === "#" ) dirPath = '\\';
```

Comment: I assume this is just a simplistic demo; that is, once the code is actually doing stuff, `dirPath` can have all kinds of stuff in it.  If that's not the case, then yeah, you're right.  :)

Comment: @cHao Exactly. It looks like the OP actually updated his answer with a new screenshot with `dirPath = '\\';`... If its got all kinds of stuff in it, they will need `if(dirPath.indexOf("#") >= 0)...`

Answer (score -1):

It makes sense to me that it shows the `\\` instead of `\`. Look at the line it has quotes.

So if the string `"\\nope"` is totally different than `"\nope"`. Now if the debugger did not have quotes surrounding the string, I would expect just one slash.

Comment: Love the anon downvotes, the reasoning is valid and IE's debugger is not the only one that does this.